# Cannot get the basic rails tutorial to work on OS X Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, osx-lion

I've been trying to get this introduction to work:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

When I try this step 'rails generate scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text' I get the following:

> Cerberus:app lab49$ rails generate scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text
>        invoke  active_record
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:66:in `connection_url_to_hash': undefined method`sub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
>     from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:34:in `block in resolve_string_connection'
>       from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord->3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:33:in`fetch'

I'm using ruby-1.9.3-p194 and rails 3.2.6 on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4.

I've spent the last few days searching the interwebs for a solution. The only progress I made was by downgrading to rails 3.1.6, but then that introduces a bug with saving models.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install `iconv` and `readline`? http://blog.merjis.com/2011/12/18/rails-3-1-ruby-1-9-3-lion-xcode-4-1/

Answer (score 0):

I compiled ruby 1.9.3p194 from source but I first had to compile [libyaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML) from source.

Remove/move the defaults files in /usr/bin

```
sudo mv rails rails-old
sudo mv bundle bundle-old
sudo mv ruby ruby-old
sudo mv gem gem-old
```

Compile libyaml

```
cd libyaml-x.x.x
./configure
make
make install
```

Compile ruby (prefix will tell it where to install during make install and with-opt-dir will tell it where to find libraries such as readline, libyaml etc. Lion should already have them in the directory if you installed xcode)

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/lib
make
make install
```

Install rails

```
gem install rails
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Also tried downgrading to Xcode 4.1 and following the instructions posted by @Connor. In the end I've installed an Ubuntu VM so I can make some progress.

Comment: Make sure if you install Xcode 4.3 or above that you go into the preferences of Xcode and install commandline tools. You can check to see if they are installed easily by running which git in a terminal window and seeing if it comes up with /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git

Comment: Also did you get any sort of errors when you tried my method?

Comment: I installed the command line tools when using 4.3. After trying your method I got the same as above.

Comment: Did you remove rvm after using my method? You'll want to move or remote rvm as well. Also if you are using a database such as mysql you will need to have it's location on your environment path or specify it during the configure command